# if(pictureBox.Image == null) in WPF

Tags: wpf

I want to control my image object is or is not `null`. `if(pictureBox.Image == null)` works C# but I cannot find a code for WPF. What should I write for this?

Comment: If you want to *control* whether `pictureBox.Image` is `null` or not, then you need assignment, not a test for equality. Second, the `PictureBox` you seem to refer to is part of the Windows Forms library, not the C# language per se.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can do this :-

```
     private PictureBox p1= null;
```

Now you can set the value as null

```
     p1= (PictureBox)image;
```

And finally you can use it as:-

```
    if(p1 == null)
```

Comment: when I write picturebox its giving warning.wpf dont allow using picturebox object.it using image object instead of picturebox

Comment: If you want to use picturebox in wpf then you will have to use WindowsFormsHost

Comment: @osunwa:- if you dont want to add the WindowwsFormsHost then "keyboardP" has given you a solution which would have been my second answer

Comment: Can I solve problem without using picturebox.is image object  
insufficient for my request?

Answer (score 1):

WPF doesn't have a `PictureBox` control. The equivalent is `Image` ([as shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750559.aspx)), so you could just do this:

```
if(myImage.Source == null) ...
```

Unless you're doing something more complicated and hosting WinForm controls in WPF?

Comment: its warning: an image source cant use as bool.it dont allow using image.source=null in if();I need another way